# Windows Mobile Sounds Not using Device Speaker

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-5.0

I have bunch of Symbol MC 70 devices.  They run Windows Mobile 5.  Most of these work just fine, but I have one that is sending the sounds (alarms and such) to the phone rather than the speaker on the device.  (The sounds play in the speaker used for listening to a phone call)

Does anyone know how to route this back to the actual phone speaker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to factory reset the device.